# How to force a Range on Fit?

Tags: fitting, polynomials

I have 1001 points between {x,-5, 5}. I wanted to fit a polynomial over the data but when i try:

```
Fit[Flatten[data], {0, x, x^2, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x]
```

... the range goes up to the number of points.

[image]

How can I constrain the range of the x-axis to {-5,5}?

Thank you.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
{{0.00012551}, {0.000172461}, {0.000219861}, {0.00026772},
```

Comment: I am not worried about showing the data - the Fit function is not giving the right Polynomial.

Comment: Does this work:   `data2=Transpose[{Subdivide[-5,5,1000], Flatten[data]}]; Fit[data2,{0, x, x^2, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x]` ?

Comment: Use `Transpose[{Range[-5,5,.01], data}]` as the input to `Fit`

Comment: @kglr Subdivide is not recognized - I have version 10.1

Comment: @JackLaVigne Your formula gives two dimensional data. Fit says it takes a regular list.

Comment: How about `datanew=Transpose[{Range[-5, 5, 0.01], Flatten[data]}]; Fit[Flatten[datanew], {0, x, x^2, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x]`?

Comment: @EdvBeq, how about `data2=Transpose[{Range[-5,5,.1], Flatten[data]}];` ?

Comment: `Fit` is happy with {{x11,f1},{x2,f2}, ...}

Comment: Nothing is working. I added a small data sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data=List/@RandomReal[10,{1001}];
data2=Transpose[{Range[-5,5,.01], Flatten@data}];
(* Subdivide[-5,5,1000] instead of Range[-5,5,.01] if you have v 10.4 *)
fit=Fit[data2,{0, x, x^2, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x]
```

> 1. +0.0310271 x+1.86717 x^2-0.166636 x^4-0.0000977394 x^5+0.00414635 x^6

```
Show[Plot[fit, {x,-5,5}, Frame->True, PlotRange->All],
      ListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]